# How to send notifications programmatically with notify-send without sudo?

Tags: python, bash

Sending notifications programmatically should be easy using `send-notify` but on Ubuntu `15.10` only when you prefix `sudo` does it work. Is there a way to configure `send-notify` for the current `$USER` or another way for scripts to use the systems notifications system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the specific command to the /etc/sudoers file.

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the following line, changing the values as needed.

```
$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/notify-send
```